# SimpleModal zindex for Eric Martin not working

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

Ok,

I'm using Eric Martins jQuery Modal solution and I need to set the zindex higher. By default it appears to set it to 1001, but I have some ads on my site that are set to 9998. Hence they are showing through the Modal window.

```
 $("#basic-modal-content").modal( 
          {
              zindex: 10000,
              onOpen: function (dialog) {
                  dialog.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function () { dialog.data.hide(); });
                  dialog.container.fadeIn('slow', function () { dialog.data.slideDown('slow'); });

              },
              onClose: function (dialog) {
                  dialog.data.fadeOut('slow', function () {
                      dialog.container.hide('slow', function () {
                          dialog.overlay.slideUp('slow', function () {
                              $.modal.close();
                          });
                      });
                  });
              }
          });
```

My code is above. This must be simple to fix, but the site possibly needs an example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

try to `zindex: 10000` to `zIndex: 10000`

(`i` is upper case)
http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/